# Invalid null pointer

Tags: c++, debugging, pointers, null, assertion

I am trying to write a program that will parse a string and give each position of word. I cannot figure out why I am getting a

> "DEBUG ASSERTION FAILED" Experssion: Invalid null pointer

window when it reaches the last word of the string.

```c
char * pointer_char;
int pos = 0;
std::string str = "This test string will fail at this word..!.   ";

int i = 0;
int length = str.length();

char * c = new char [str.size()+1];
std::copy(str.begin(), str.end(), c);
c[str.size()] = '\0';

cout << "Testing string is " << str << endl << endl;
pointer_char = strtok (c," ");
while(pointer_char != NULL)
{
    cout << pointer_char << endl;
    pointer_char = strtok(NULL, " .!");
    string word = pointer_char;

    size_t found= str.find(word);
    if (found!=string::npos)
    cout << "Position of " << word << " found at: " << int(found) << endl;
    system("pause");
}
return 0;
```

Comment: Your follow-up `strtok()` is a little premature. It should be at the *bottom* of your loop; not the top.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is you aren't checking the return value of strtok.

```
    pointer_char = strtok(NULL, " .!");
    string word = pointer_char;
```

You're only testing it at the top of the loop.

```
    pointer_char = strtok(nullptr, " .!");
    if (pointer_char == nullptr)
        break;
```